# Add the missing numbers in the table in order

Tags: python, pandas

I need modify a csv file with pandas. I have the following table:

```
Interface   Description
1           Used
2           Used
3           Used
4           Used
6           Used
8           Used
12          Used
17          Used
```

I need to match the "Interface" column with a range of 1, 20, complete the table with the missing numbers and place the word "free" in the "Description" column and order it like this:

```
Interface   Description
1           Used
2           Used
3           Used
4           Used
5           free
6           Used
7           free
8           Used
9           free
10          free
11          free
12          Used
13          free
14          free
15          free
16          free
17          Used
18          free
19          free
20          free
```

Comment: What's your question? If you're looking for help with this, what have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? For example, do you know how to make a range and use `.mask()`/`.where()`? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: (On second thought, `.mask()`/`.where()` aren't very helpful here. I might have been confused with `.fillna()`.)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism, I will try to be clearer, I tried to use a for loop and within it an if to iterate over the range 1,20 but it was giving many errors and I did not think it would be very helpful to comment on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `merge` in combination with `fillna`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Interface': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 17],
    'Description': 'Used'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Interface': range(1, 21)}).merge(df, how="left").fillna("free")
```

Comment: cool! works! It is much simpler than what I was trying, I will study the solution and if I have any questions I will ask you, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `reindex`

```
df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,21)).fillna('free').reset_index()



    Interface Description
0           1        Used
1           2        Used
2           3        Used
3           4        Used
4           5        free
5           6        Used
6           7        free
7           8        Used
8           9        free
9          10        free
10         11        free
11         12        Used
12         13        free
13         14        free
14         15        free
15         16        free
16         17        Used
17         18        free
18         19        free
19         20        free
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to expose missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
interface = {'Interface' : range(1, 21)}
df.complete(interface, fill_value='free')
    Interface Description
0           1        Used
1           2        Used
2           3        Used
3           4        Used
4           5        free
5           6        Used
6           7        free
7           8        Used
8           9        free
9          10        free
10         11        free
11         12        Used
12         13        free
13         14        free
14         15        free
15         16        free
16         17        Used
17         18        free
18         19        free
19         20        free
```